# Proper way to show which SSH commands you are running

Tags: bash, networking, ssh

I am trying to pass an array of commands to a NID device via SSH, then storing the output into a variable. I can't figure out a efficient way to display which command is running in the output.

I can get it working by looping the the array and doing 7 separate SSH sessions. Which is very slow.

```
n_info=$(sshpass -p "-PW-" ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=false admin@$nid_ip << EOF
        ${c_array[0]}
        ${c_array[1]}
        ${c_array[2]}
        ${c_array[3]}
        ${c_array[4]}
        ${c_array[5]}
        ${c_array[6]} 
        exit
EOF
)
        echo "$i"
        echo "$n_info"| sed "s/ACCEDIAN:>//g"
```

**Expected:**

```
[show log]

log text 

log text 

log text 

[show config]

config text

config text

config text
```

**Actual:**

```
log text 

log text 

log text 

config text

config text

config text
```

Commands are not static**

Comment: Add output of `declare -p c_array` to your question.

Comment: Just add `echo [show log]` and `echo [show config]` at the appropriate locations into your here-doc.

Comment: Add `set -x` to your here document?

Comment: If you can't execute the echo on the nid, you might be able to reuse your ssh connection. which ssh client are you using, specifically? openssh has `-o ControlMaster` / `-o ControlPath` / `-O` for example

Comment: our rundeck instance is running openssh, I will look into that

Comment: @Cyrus where would I add the set?

Comment: In a new line before `${c_array[0]}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest/cleanest solution, if it's possible, is to run the echo commands on the nid.
Assuming headers contain no shell special characters:

```
sshpass -p "-PW-" ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=false admin@$nid_ip << EOF
    echo '[${h_array[0]}]'; ${c_array[0]}
    echo '[${h_array[1]}]'; ${c_array[1]}
    echo '[${h_array[2]}]'; ${c_array[2]}
    echo '[${h_array[3]}]'; ${c_array[3]}
    echo '[${h_array[4]}]'; ${c_array[4]}
    echo '[${h_array[5]}]'; ${c_array[5]}
    echo '[${h_array[6]}]'; ${c_array[6]} 
    exit
EOF | sed "s/ACCEDIAN:>//g"
```

If you are using openssh as the ssh client, it has options to use a single control connection. Something like:

```
REMOTE="admin@$nid"

CP_DIR="/tmp/sshctl/$$"
CP="$CP_DIR/"%L-%r@%h:%p"
mkdir -p "$CP_DIR"

sshpass -p "-PW-" \
ssh -q -nNf -o ControlMaster=yes -o ControlPath="${CP}" \
    -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=false "$REMOTE"

# !!! check you have a connection !!!
# it may work to wrap "sshpass ..." with "if ! sshpass ...; then do_error; fi"

(
    for i in {0..6}; do
        echo "[$h_array[$i]}]"
        ssh -o ControlPath="${CP}" \
            -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=false "$REMOTE" "${c_array[$i]}"
    done
    ssh -O exit -o ControlPath="$CP" "$REMOTE"
) | sed "s/ACCEDIAN:>//g"

rm -r "$CP_DIR"
```